SwiftUI ViewModel not being deinit and causing memory leak
I am developing a Mac OS app on Xcode that pulls Football standings from an API and displays it in a View. I noticed that my memory keeps increasing and after using the Xcode Memory Graph, I believe that my problem is that the ViewModel is not being deinit and thus still being allocated memory. For example, in the picture below, going back and forth from the BundesligaView 3 times has created 3 separate models.

The code below is much simplified from my original App. When moving from LeagueIndex -> BundesligaView, a viewModel is created. I am not sure if I should add a [weak self] somewhere?
// VIEWMODEL
import Foundation

class BundesligaViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var standings: [BundesligaModel] = []
    @Published var loadingState: LoadingState = .idle
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchData(_ league: String? = nil) async {
        loadingState = .loading
        do { 
            standings = try await NetworkManager.shared.fetchBundesligaStandings(league!)
            loadingState = .loaded
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching standings: \(error)")
            loadingState = .error
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        print("VIEWMODEL CREATED")
    }

    deinit {
        print("VIEWMODEL DEINT")
    }
}

enum LoadingState {
    case idle
    case loading
    case loaded
    case error
}

// MODEL
import Foundation

struct BundesligaModel: Codable {
    let teamName: String
    let shortName: String
    let points: Int
    let matches: Int
    let won: Int
    let draw: Int
    let lost: Int
    let goals: Int
    let opponentGoals: Int
    let goalDiff: Int
}

// VIEWS
struct LeagueIndex: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: BundesligaTable(league: "Bundesliga")) {
                Text("Bundesliga")
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct Footer: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: LeagueIndex()) {
            Text("League Index").foregroundStyle(Color.red)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct BundesligaTable: View {
    let league: String
    @StateObject private var viewModel = BundesligaViewModel()
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25)),
        GridItem(.fixed(25))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(Array(viewModel.standings.enumerated()), id: \.element.teamName) { index, team in
                    Text("\(index + 1)")
                    Text(team.shortName)
                    Text("\(team.matches)")
                    Text("\(team.won)")
                    Text("\(team.draw)")
                    Text("\(team.lost)")
                    Text("\(team.goals)")
                    Text("\(team.opponentGoals)")
                    Text("\(team.goalDiff)")
                    Text("\(team.points)")
                }
            }
            Footer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .task { 
            await viewModel.fetchData(league)
        }
    }
}

// NETWORK MANAGER

class NetworkManager {
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    
    func fetchData<T: Decodable>(from endpoint: String) async throws -> T {
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}

extension NetworkManager {
    func fetchBundesligaStandings(_ league: String) async throws -> [BundesligaModel] {
        return try await fetchData(from: "https://api.openligadb.de/getbltable/bl1/2023")
    }
    // Other leagues here
}


First of all three instances is not yet memory leak. It can be that iOS won't immediately dispose of views, and so you see them. See if it accumulates these views more and more, and even if you navigate to another part of the app. But also when you are already on memory view, you should be able to see what holds that instance if you indeed confirm it's held.

In SwiftUI use the View struct as your view model. Use .task to get results from async funcs.

In iOS versions 17.0, 17.1 and 17.2 there have been a memory leak with Observables with idiomatic code like yours, when in addition a sheet has been presented in this view. You may try the following: for every reference to viewModel in the body, replace it with a function defined in this view, which performs the access. The actual issue was more complex - but it may help.

Found the issue! I had a custom Footer which navigated to LeagueIndex when in BundesligaView. It was supposed to act as a back button in the NavigationStack, however it was wrongly implemented causing the View and therefore the ViewModel to retain.
Old Footer:
struct Footer: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: LeagueIndex()) {
                Text("League Index").foregroundStyle(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

New Footer:
struct Footer: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                dismiss()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text("League Index").foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

